# how to build a simple lock (mutex) on nios II cpu

Tags: c, assembly, intel-fpga, nios

I am trying to build a simple video game for a university course using altera DE0 or DE2 or DE1-SoC boards, i looked at the isa for the nios II cpu there is no atomic test-and-set instruction in the ISA. how would i build a simple lock here, anything that enforces mutual exclusion for a tiny period will work.

we are gonna have code that is gonna run from `main()` and code that will run in the Interrupt Service Routine, and i want to put locks on some variables, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the Nios II architecture doesn't have atomic test-and-set instructions. Instead for synchronization of shared resources between multiple Nios II processors, the architecture uses an "Hardware Mutex Core".  It works as a shared peripheral that provides an atomic test-and-test operation. You can read more about it in [Altera's Creating Multiprocessor Nios II Systems Tutorial](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/tt/tt_nios2_multiprocessor_tutorial.pdf).

However, you probably don't an atomic test-and-set operation. You can make any sequence of instructions atomic with respect to interrupts on a single core system simply by disabling interrupts.

Comment: In fact, mutex doesn't protect between task and ISR.  You _have_ to do cli/sti.  mutex only works for core-to-core.  If multicore with ISR: `cli,lock,do stuff,unlock,sti`

Comment: hmm, yes disabling interrupts momentarily instead of a lock should solve my problem. but i didnt understand why mutex wouldnt work between task and ISR, could you please explain that a bit more.

Comment: @user2567411 Consider the following sequence: `task does lock(), does stuff, ISR interrupts, ISR does lock() and is blocked: deadlock!`  A weak alternative: `task does lock(), ..., ISR interrupts, does trylock() [which fails], ISR exits, task does unlock(), ISR interrupts again, does trylock() [which succeeds], does stuff, does unlock(), ISR returns`  Note that `trylock()` tests the lock but doesn't block if it can't get it.  It returns 1=locked, 0=failed.

Comment: hmm yea it occurred to me just before checking this that the ISR cant wait even for tiny period, because on a single core machine as long as it is running, `main()` cant release the lock, but the weak version could work, if the ISR has idempotent things to do, it can just try to do it and if not possible then just return and wait for the next interrupt to try again. but in my case its too risky to assume that i can do everything in such idempotent ops half way thru the project. I am just gonna use disable/enable interrupts as the lock